# Deleting files in higher directory

Tags: php, file, delete-file, unlink, chdir

I'm having problems deleting a file from a higher directory, I found this post and tried it but no luck....:

> gotdalife at gmail dot com 25-Sep-2008
>   02:04
>
> To anyone who's had a problem with the
>   permissions denied error, it's
>   sometimes caused when you try to
>   delete a file that's in a folder
>   higher in the hierarchy to your
>   working directory (i.e. when trying to
>   delete a path that starts with "../").
>
> So to work around this problem, you
>   can use chdir() to change the working
>   directory to the folder where the file
>   you want to unlink is located.

```
<?php
>     $old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory
>     chdir($path_to_file);
>     unlink($filename);
>     chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory     ?>
```

here is the code that I currently have:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] !=md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){

    require_once ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');
    $url = absolute_url();
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}  



$folder = $_GET['folder'];
$filename = $_GET['name'];
$path = "../gallery/photos/$folder";

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    if ($_POST['sure'] == 'Yes') {  

        $old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory
        chdir($path);
        unlink($filename);
        chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory  

    }
    else{

        echo '<p>The photo has NOT been deleted.</p>';
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error message :

> Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]:
>   No error in
>   J:\xampp\htdocs\bunker\admin\delete_file.php
>   on line 37

line 37 being:

```
unlink($filename);
```

can anybody see what I've done wrong?

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_Mp0d-dsENrg/S15lV3B8PHI/AAAAAAAAiA8/UTTVHEEwD44/s400/59934678.jpg

Comment: Have you tried explicitly declaring the path? (e.g., no "../" but an actual hard path) Don't know where that will leave you if it works/doesn't work but might be a good test :)

Comment: Ummm, do you have any idea how bad of an idea that is? I mean passing raw input to `chdir` and running `unlink`...?  At least do some sensitization to prevent `delete_file.php?folder=../../../../../etc&file=passwd`...  (permissions will likely prevent that, but there are bound to be files it can delete that are just as bad to you at least)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use absolute filepath names.

I'd define the filedir as a constant in your config, then concatenate so you have an absolute filepath, then make a call to unlink().

Btw: I hope you know your code is *highly* insecure.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43511

and here

http://php.bigresource.com/Track-php-03TimDKO/

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10357994

Though I wouldnt recommend doing this, as per the comments above. Is there the option for a different approach?

Comment: sorry im very new to php so i'm unaware of any other approaches, i'm open to suggestions... all i need to do is delete a file selected but it seems to be causing me problem after problem.